# the insert method not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, nsstring

I am working on sqlite database , trying to insert into database but it is not working proper. I searched some post and also write reset and finalize statement.

---

```
(void)addLimittypeForeign
{
  // Create insert statement for the person

  if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
         @"insert into Limittabel (limitid,limitAmt,Profileid) Values (?,?,?)"];

    char *errmsg=nil;

    if(sqlite3_exec(database, [querySQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg)
         != SQLITE_OK )
    {
      NSLog(@"YES THE DATA HAS BEEN WRITTEN SUCCESSFULLY");
    }
  }
  sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

---

Please Help Me.Thanks

Comment: What does "it is not working proper" mean, exactly?  What worked and what didn't?

Answer (score 0):

use this code for insertion is database .... change code according to your requirement...working fine for me...

```
-(void) insertDataIntoDatabase
{
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dataBaseName.sqlite"];

NSLog(@"%@",sender);

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[quoteDic objectForKey:@"bookmark"]);
    NSLog(@"%d",[[quoteDic objectForKey:@"quoteId"] intValue]);
    NSString *sqlStatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tableName (frndName,frndDescription,frndAddress,frndMobile,frndEmail,frndCollege,frndCompany) Values('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",[frndName text],[frndDescription text],[frndAddress text],[frndMobile text],[frndEmail text],[frndCollege text],[frndCompany text]];

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
    }
    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {

        //sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while Updating data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Update!!"
                                                        message:@"Your record Updated"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Thankyou"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: -(void)addLimitType:(DepositCash *)depositobj
{
    [depositobj addLimittypeForeign];
    [arrLimitType addObject:depositobj];
}

Comment: This type of method using in Appdelegate

Comment: just put it in appdelegate.m.. NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentDir = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];
 databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"QuotesApp.sqlite"];
 [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

Comment: -(void)checkAndCreateDatabase
{
    BOOL success;
    
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
 
    if(success) return;
 
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"QuotesApp.sqlite"];
 
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
 
    [fileManager release];
}

Comment: and in appdelegate.h    NSString *databasePath;

Comment: database lock problem.i m using foreign key